# Bash script for viewing VM quickly the hypervisor (KVM)

Tags: awk, sed, kvm, hypervisor

I'm looking for a way to get a quick view of the hypervisor when looking for a guest virtual machine (running KVM).

I have a script that collects all my hypervisors (with guest VMs) in a single text file separated by a line break (see example below):

```
Hypervisor: hypervisor1
 ID    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     vm1                            running
 2     vm2                            running
 3     vm3                            running
 4     vm4                            running

Hypervisor: hypervisor2
 ID    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     vm1                            running
 2     vm2                            running
 3     vm3                            running
 4     vm4                            running
 5     vm5                            running
 6     vm6                            running

ETC....
```

I tried with:

```
grep -v -E "(-|Name)" file.txt |
awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' |
tr "\n" " " |
sed "s/ * / -> /"
```

But I get this:

```
hypervisor1 -> vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4  hypervisor2 vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4 vm5 vm6
```

My question is: how do I get this displayed?

```
hypervisor1 -> vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4
hypervisor2 -> vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4 vm5 vm6
etc.. etc...
```

Comment: This is just sting parsing. Has nothing to do with kvm/hypervisors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '/Hypervisor:/ {printf "%s ->", $2} # row contains Hypervisor:
     $0==""        {print ""}           # row is empty
     $1~/[0-9]/    {printf " %s", $2}   # first column contains digit
     END           {print ""}' file     # add a trailing newline
```

Output:

```
hypervisor1 -> vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4
hypervisor2 -> vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4 vm5 vm6
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '
/Hypervisor:/{
  if(value1){
    print value,value1
  }
  found=value1=""
  value=$NF
  next
}
/ID/{
  found=1
  next
}
found && match($0,/vm[0-9]+/){
  value1=(value1?value1 OFS:"")substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
END{
  if(value1){
    print value,value1
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
/Hypervisor:/{                    ##Checking condition if line contains Hypervisor: then do following.
  if(value1){                     ##Checking if value1 is NOT NULL.
    print value,value1            ##Printing value and value1 here.
  }
  found=value1=""                 ##Nullify found and value1 here.
  value=$NF                       ##Setting value as last field here.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/ID/{                             ##Checking condition if ID is found in current line then do following.
  found=1                         ##Setting found to 1 here.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found && match($0,/vm[0-9]+/){    ##Checking if found is SET and match function to match vm values.
  value1=(value1?value1 OFS:"")substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                                  ##Creating value1 which has matched sub string and keep adding its values to it.
}
END{                              ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(value1){                     ##Checking condition if value1 is set then do following.
    print value,value1            ##Printing value and value1 here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/Hypervisor:/{s/.*: //;:a;x;/./{s/\n/ -> /;s// /g;p};x;h;d}
        /^\s*[0-9]+\s*(\S+).*/{s//\1/;H};$!d;ba' file
```

Store the relevant details in the hold space and at change of hypervisor or end-of-file, manipulate the stored values into the required format.